# Access file and read/write from shared/network folder using python

Tags: python, file

i want to read and write data from network folder, so far i have tried
os.open("\u drive path") , open("\u drive path")
but it says accesss or permission denied
but when i use
os.startfile("\u drive path")

Comment: What is `\u`? Are you on Windows? Is the drive mapped to "U"? You need to escape the backslash in python string literals, or use raw strings, or simply use forward slashes. Perhaps the path should be `r"U:\drive path"`. You may even be table to use a UNC, such as `//servername/sharename/path".

Comment: You don't show a proper path, so are leaving us guessing, but instead of `os.open(whaterver)`, try `print(whatever)` and post both code and the resulting printed string. Then we can make better guesses about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I always try r strings when connecting to a network drive (especially if using pandas) try doing this to put the file into a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
desired_file = r'\\networkdrive\folder\file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(desired_file, , encoding='utf-8')
```

This makes it easier for us to just look at as people with the r string but if you use

```
print(desired_file)
```

You can see that python reads it the way that it needs to be formatted for pandas

Comment: `r''` strings are overall a good practice when specifying a path with backslashes.

Comment: it did not work for me

Comment: What error did you get? Additionally, I notice in your post you say u:\ drive as a network drive. This is not actually a "u:\" drive but most likely something along the lines of \\filepath\morefilepath\folder\file. Can you please verify that you are using the full UNC path with your "desired_file" variable

Comment: yes i am using correct file path and verified it. This is network drive i have already mapped the network drive and i named it as U Drive and its path or target value is "\\123.22.123\folder1\folder"   my error : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Comment: Are you using "\\123.22.123\folder1\folder\file.csv"? that is a key element (only asking since you didn't specify)

Comment: "\\123.22.123\folder1\folder\file.txt"   file

Comment: I updated the code for something you can try I found elsewhere the worked